# What is the time complexity for this? I think it is O(n) but its not?

Tags: python, time-complexity

What is the time complexity for this? I think it is O(n) but its not??

```
def f5(n):
    for i in range(0,n,2):
        print(i)  
    if n<=0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + f5(n-5)
```

Comment: no it is quadratic, because it recursively calls itself in a linear fashion

Comment: actually the answer is O(logn) and I still don't get how that's even possible. Btw why do you think its quadratic? I see logarithmic for the for loop and n for the recursive

Comment: It's *definitely* not O(log n). The loop is not logarithmic, for any input n, it.makes n/2 iterations, i.e O(n)

Answer (score 3):

No, this is O(n<sup>2</sup>) because it's essentially a nested loop when you account for the recursive call running from 0..n. Be careful: the outer recursive call "loop" runs in steps of 5 and the explicit function body loop runs in steps of 2 but you always disregard these constant factors when considering time complexity. If the recursive call was `n // 2`, for example, it'd be another matter entirely (that'd be log(n) on its own, and combined with an linear inner loop gives O(n log(n))--nested loops are multiplied).

Comment: If you're going to mention the alternative recursive call, you might as well say what that complexity would be.

Comment: actually the answer is O(logn) and I still don't get how that's even possible

Comment: That's incorrect. Where are you getting that idea from? Even without the recursive call, `for i in range(0,n,2):` is immediately O(n), so O(log(n)) is completely out of the picture here. For something to be logarithmic, the typical pattern is repeated division by half (binary search, etc), not stepping over an array in a fixed increment as is the case here.

Comment: Yes, I see logarithmic for the for loop and n for the recursive which is why my answer was O(n) but I was answering some questions from udemy academy, I got wrong answer. It stated that it was O(logn)

Comment: Udemy is wrong--there's nothing logarithmic here. I suggest they fix the quiz, assuming everything was copied without error here. If you're not convinced, go ahead and code it up and compare the rate of growth as `n` increases using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) which is a canonical O(log(n)) algorithm.

Comment: @Pravash "Udemy says" is not an argument. As explained by ggorlen, it's O(n) right off the bat due to that for loop

Comment: Got it guys. I did O(n) but got it wrong. Thanks anyways.